# JavaScript and function variables

Tags: php, javascript, variables

Let us say I have this on a html form...

```
<input id="world" type="text" onblur="return hello ('world');" />
```

And in my script I have

```
function hello (id) {
      document.write(id);
}
```

It returns world as expected. If I use it like this though...

```
function hello (id) {
      var val = $('#' + id).val();
      $.post("ajax.php", {
          id: val,
      });
}
```

Then the id returns **Array**, how can I make it return username like I want it to.

Thanks.

As requested the php side of things...

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['username'])) {
    $q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE username = ?");
    $q -> execute(array($_REQUEST['username']));

    if (strlen($_REQUEST['username']) < 3) {
        echo '<div class="error">Has to be at least 3 characters</div>';
    }   
    elseif ($q -> rowCount() > 0) {
        echo '<div class="error">Username already taken</div>';
    }
    else {
         echo '<div class="success">Username available</div>';
    }
}
else {
    echo $_REQUEST;
}
```

If it should equals username like it should do then the ajax is successfull else it will echo the result of `$_REQUEST` which is at the moment **Array**.

**UPDATE**

Calling the function:

```
<input id="world" type="text" onblur="return ajax ('username');" />
```

The original function:

```
function ajax (id) {

var val = $('#' + id).val();

$('.loading').fadeIn().delay(100);

$.post("ajax.php", {id: val};

}
```

I did a var dump on the Array and it returns the string that was entered into the textfield?? Not the id that I passed to the function?!? Why is this happening?

Example of `var_dump($_REQUEST)`

```
array
 'id' => string 'dadadas' (length=7)
```

Comment: I think it'd only return an array if it matched more than one element to read the value from. How many elements id="world" do you have on the page?

Comment: you need to show more code of the server side (ajax.php) ... or simply be sure that ajax.php return the value you want or process the array to print the value ...

Comment: The supplied function should be returning `undefined`, not an array, since there is no return statement here. Is this code posted a simplification?

Comment: jQuery only returns one element for an ID selector at all times. http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/gBjnJ/

Comment: I highly suggest you explicitly use a return clause.  It's not strictly necessary, but it does make the code more clear on what is happening.  I don't use returns if I don't care about the return value, but it sounds as though you do care about the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP code is checking for `username`:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['username'])) {
```

Change your code to provide `username` instead of `id`

```
function hello (id) {
    var val = $('#' + id).val();
    $.post("ajax.php", {
        username: val
    });
}
```

`$_REQUEST` is an array, which you are `echo`ing because the request parameter `username` is not being found.

Comment: `id` is never the username - it is the identifier of the input field containing the username.  `var val = $('#' + id).val();` assigns the username to val and `username:val` tells the server that `$_REQUEST["username"]` is equal to `val`.

Comment: so how would I instead put the css id of the textfield in there instead?? I am wanting it so I can call the function for any input and not to have to define the name of $_REQUEST but append the id to it?

Comment: Because you are using AJAX and not submitting a form, the server won't know what to do with the `id` - just send it the value.

Comment: Ah ok, it just means writing a seperate function for each ajax request and only changing that snippet of code, maybe I'll sort it one day, thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You've probably got more than one element on the page with the same "id" value.  That's not valid markup, as "id" values must be unique across the entire page.

*edit* — re-using "id" values is indeed a bad idea, but it wouldn't cause that behavior. I suspect there may be other code involved that would explain more. I'll leave this answer here but nobody should vote for it :-)

Comment: Only one ID of world on the page :-/

Comment: It is invalid, but would not cause this behaviour.  http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/gBjnJ

Comment: Yes @pimdvd I agree - after I typed the answer I started scratching my head because it seems pretty odd that jQuery would do that.